# How to get result on Where Clause satisfied some condition?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am using  **MySQL** database table **scholarship_discount**. where I have three fields that are **maxPercentage, min Percentage and name**. So I want to run a query for getting rows if all fields satisfy my condition. I am using Laravel 5.6 Framework. problem is when i am running this query into **MySql Workbench** then getting correct result but when tries through Laravel then getting wrong result.

**Problem Example ::**

If I gives  **user value as 78** then i get **row id 5** , else **96** then **row is 1**.ok  no problem.   Using  **mysql workbench**.

but when i gives **98 ,96,97,99** then i get no result . why? i don't know.  No any record deleted. my meant it should be return **row id 1** but gives me **blank Array** [].

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM confidence.scholarship_discounts where name='ssc' and 
 (maxPer >= 100 or  maxPer = 100 ) and `scholarship_discounts`.`deleted_at` is null 
 order by id DESC;
```

my search condition is **MaxPercentage** should be greater than to **user Value**.
My database record is:

```
id    name      maxPercentage   minPercentage    discountPercentage
1     HSC           100            95                 10
2     HSC           95             90                  7
3     HSC           90             85                  6
4     HSC           85             80                  5
5     HSC           80             75                  10
6     HSC           75             70                  7
7     HSC           60             50                  6
```

So, according to this table if I give 95 as value, then the query should return  row id 1.

So it's better if a solution available on Laravel eloquent then please describe it.
Can i filter or search row between  maxPercentage { value } minPercentage.
like

```
75 myValue 70
```

Comment: In your query, you have `maxPercentage <= 90`. It won't return row 1 because the `maxPercentage` is 100. You should do `maxPercentage >= 90`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem self. actually   i was doing wrong with table fields. i was selected wrong fields for compare value with my input.

```
ScholarshipDiscount::where( 'name' ,'ssc' )
  ->where( function( $q ) use ( $request ) {
      $q-> where('minPer' ,'<=', $request->ssc );
      $q->  orWhere('minPer' , $request->ssc );
      $q->  orWhere('maxPer' , $request->ssc );
  } )->orderBy('id','asc')->first();
```

I checked my condition with is solution and every time i was getting my result.

Answer (score 0):

`where maxPercentage <= 90` - This means that the maximum percentage has to be equal to or GREATER than 90% *If you changed this value to 95 then yes, only the row with id=1 would be returned*.

`minPercentage >= 90` - Means the minimum persentage must be LESS than 90%

If this isn't what you're asking please elaborate further. The method you've chosen to do this is probably the most efficient way, if not just the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Ok thanks for this.. but can you test my query and correct if it is wrong. because i have told my condition but using that query i am not getting result as i want.

Comment: `return    $data = ScholarshipDiscount::  `
                   `where('maxPer' ,'>=', $request->value )`  
                   `->orWhere('maxPer',$request->value)  `  
                      `->orderBy('id','desc')->get();`

Comment: My laravel code but i am getting not correct result .

Comment: If you're not getting the result you want, what result are you trying to get from it, and what results are you actually getting?

Comment: Yes , i have updated my question. please read from beginning then you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
return $data = ScholarshipDiscount::where(function($q) use ($request){
               return $q->where('maxPercentage' ,'>=', $request->value)
                        ->orWhere('maxPercentage',$request->value);
                })->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```